# Licence issues using ContentTools WYSIWYG editor

Tags: licensing, mit

We have been searching for a Html editor for couple of days, we have visited some editors too, but nothing fits our requirement, and then someone suggested us to use [ContentTools WYSIWYG editor](http://getcontenttools.com/), which is really an excellent editor, we are even open to use paid version, but we can't see anything to pay for it, now we just want to confirm, if we integrate this editor in our pages, do we need to take care anything related to licencing, or any other legal issue. Our portal will not distributing this product(Editor) directly , but as our core business model, we sell ads on portal and making money in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That software [uses the MIT license](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/blob/master/LICENSE). It is very short; here it is in its entirety:

> Copyright (c) 2014 Getme Limited (http://getme.co.uk)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

In short, you can do whatever you would like, as long as any copy of the software mentions that the editor is available under this license.